# Search in all tables

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-6

My problem is I dont know how to search all tables and search in all fields of the tables. I have no idea.
Just one textbox such as YouTube, results will be written in the source.
Can someone give me an idea? I would be very pleased.
I have to do it on the **Asp.net MVC**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source:
http://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/

You can use my query here, should be simpler then having to create stored procedures for each database you want to search:

[FullParam SQL Blog](https://fullparam.wordpress.com/2012/09/07/fck-it-i-am-going-to-search-all-tables-all-collumns/)

```
/* Reto Egeter, fullparam.wordpress.com */

DECLARE @SearchStrTableName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnName nvarchar(255), @SearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(255), @SearchStrInXML bit, @FullRowResult bit, @FullRowResultRows int
SET @SearchStrColumnValue = '%searchthis%' /* use LIKE syntax */
SET @FullRowResult = 1
SET @FullRowResultRows = 3
SET @SearchStrTableName = NULL /* NULL for all tables, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrColumnName = NULL /* NULL for all columns, uses LIKE syntax */
SET @SearchStrInXML = 0 /* Searching XML data may be slow */

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
CREATE TABLE #Results (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), ColumnValue nvarchar(max),ColumnType nvarchar(20))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = '',@ColumnName nvarchar(128),@ColumnType nvarchar(20), @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue nvarchar(110), @QuotedSearchStrColumnName nvarchar(110)
SET @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue = QUOTENAME(@SearchStrColumnValue,'''')
DECLARE @ColumnNameTable TABLE (COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(128),DATA_TYPE nvarchar(20))

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND TABLE_NAME LIKE COALESCE(@SearchStrTableName,TABLE_NAME)
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)), 'IsMSShipped') = 0
    )
    IF @TableName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sql = 'SELECT QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME),DATA_TYPE
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(''' + @TableName + ''', 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN (' + CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SearchStrColumnValue,'%',''),'_',''),'[',''),']',''),'-','')) = 1 THEN '''tinyint'',''int'',''smallint'',''bigint'',''numeric'',''decimal'',''smallmoney'',''money'',' ELSE '' END + '''char'',''varchar'',''nchar'',''nvarchar'',''timestamp'',''uniqueidentifier''' + CASE @SearchStrInXML WHEN 1 THEN ',''xml''' ELSE '' END + ')
                AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE COALESCE(' + CASE WHEN @SearchStrColumnName IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE '''' + @SearchStrColumnName + '''' END  + ',COLUMN_NAME)'
        INSERT INTO @ColumnNameTable
        EXEC (@sql)
        WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME FROM @ColumnNameTable)
        BEGIN
            PRINT @ColumnName
            SELECT TOP 1 @ColumnName = COLUMN_NAME,@ColumnType = DATA_TYPE FROM @ColumnNameTable
            SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + ''',''' + @ColumnName + ''',' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'LEFT(CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX)), 4096),''' 
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + '),'''
            ELSE 'LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 4096),''' END + @ColumnType + ''' 
                    FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC(@sql)
            IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 IF @FullRowResult = 1 
            BEGIN
                SET @sql = 'SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@FullRowResultRows AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ''' + @TableName + ''' AS [TableFound],''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS [ColumnFound],''FullRow>'' AS [FullRow>],*' +
                    ' FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                    ' WHERE ' + CASE @ColumnType WHEN 'xml' THEN 'CAST(' + @ColumnName + ' AS nvarchar(MAX))' 
                    WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr('+ @ColumnName + ')'
                    ELSE @ColumnName END + ' LIKE ' + @QuotedSearchStrColumnValue
                EXEC(@sql)
            END
            DELETE FROM @ColumnNameTable WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
        END 
    END
END
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```